# Merging a dataframe with another dataframe with constant values from the first dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to merge two data frames, df1 and df2:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['a'],
    'B': ['b'],
    'C': ['c']
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'W': [1, 2, 3],
    'X': [4, 5, 6],
    'Y': [7, 8, 9],
    'Z': [10, 11, 12]
})
```

df1: (will always have only one row)

[image]

df2: (can have any number of rows)

[image]

In a way that all the columns of df1 are added to the df2 dataframe with all the rows having the same values present in the df1 dataframe.

I have tried:

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2], sort=False, axis=1)
```

But this is giving me NaN's:

[image]

But i want all the rows to have the same constant value that is present in df1 like:

[image]

I would also like to maintain having the new columns from df1 be before the columns of df2 as above.
What might be the most efficient way to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do an `outer merge` on an artificially created `key`:

```
df1.assign(key=1).merge(df2.assign(key=1), on='key').drop('key', axis=1)

   A  B  C  W  X  Y   Z
0  a  b  c  1  4  7  10
1  a  b  c  2  5  8  11
2  a  b  c  3  6  9  12
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) with selecting first row and then change order of columns by [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df3 = df2.assign(**df1.iloc[0]).reindex(df1.columns.union(df2.columns, sort=False),axis=1)
print (df3)
   A  B  C  W  X  Y   Z
0  a  b  c  1  4  7  10
1  a  b  c  2  5  8  11
2  a  b  c  3  6  9  12
```

Or add rows to `df1` by `df2.index` with `method='ffill'`:

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1.reindex(df2.index, method='ffill'),df2], sort=False, axis=1)
print (df3)
   A  B  C  W  X  Y   Z
0  a  b  c  1  4  7  10
1  a  b  c  2  5  8  11
2  a  b  c  3  6  9  12
```